# Смена цвета текста по нажатию

Tags: android, color, android-textview

У меня есть `TextView` в котором я задал `textColor`. Как мне сделать так чтобы по нажатию на этот `TextView` текст менял цвет а при отпускании кнопки он становился изначальным.

Мой `TextView`

```
 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txv_task"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:text="@string/task"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

Java с элементом кода

```
TextView txv_task = requireView().findViewById(R.id.txv_task);
        txv_task.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Navigation.findNavController(view)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_navigation_menu_list_to_navigation_FragmentTasks);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаете `drawable` ресурс с вот таким кодом:

```
// ненужные состояния убрать или же добавить свои по аналогии

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

Указываете в нем нужные цвета на каждое нужное вам состояние. После чего в атрибутах вашего `TextView` задаете этот drawable как `textColor`

```
android:textColor="@drawable/selected_color"
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так.

```
    private void colors() {
    color.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    color.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    color.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Решение Sergei Buvaka мне нравится больше)